# How to use Regex to extract variable names and values (separated by =) (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

Why the following regex doesn't work?

```
(?<name>[^\s]+?)\w?=\w?(?<value>[^\s]+?);
```

https://regex101.com/r/q7NTdS/1

I have a string:

```
a = 2.234;
b = Hello;

random text...

c =2;
```

And I want to extract "a", "b", and "c" (without white spaces) and their values "2.234", "Hello" and "2". What should I change?

Comment: You just forgot that there is a space before and after the `=`. If you replace the `=` in you regex with ` = ` everything works fine.

Comment: Did you mean to use `\s` instead of `\w`?

Comment: Please include the expression within the question. Questions on StackOverflow should be self-contained, meaning all details required to reasonably answer the question should be provided within the question itself (for various reasons, [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) being the main one).

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes what a stupid mistake thank you

Comment: You might also use a version without non greedy quantifiers by excluding matching the `=` sign  and the `;` like `(?<name>[^\s=]+)\s*=\s*(?<value>[^\s;]+);` and matching optional whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches any word character which does not include whitespace. Try using `\s` which matches any kind of invisible character. `(?<name>[^\s]+?)\s?=\s?(?<value>[^\s]+?);` - [@regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cs2fsp/1).

Answer (score 0):

Let's define what `name` and `value` are. If

> **name** *must* start from letter and *can* contain letters, digits or `_`

> **value** can contain any symbols but doesn't start or end by white spaces

> `name` and `value` *must* be separated by `=` and optional white spaces.

> the whole string *must* end with `;` and white spaces

then pattern can be

```
\s*(?<name>\p{L}[\p{L}_0-9]*)\s*=\s*(?<value>.*?)\s*;\s*
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y7piN7)